# Is there a Design Pattern for implementing a parametric search feature w/o using SQL in Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, rule-engine

I'm not really sure what the best approach is for designing what I would call a "parametric" search or rule engine.  I have a Java object which has several fields.  I will run the java object against several queries in order to see if it meets certain criteria.

An example i can think of is the bug search feature in bugzilla.  In the UI you select things like the Status, Resolution, Severity.  Then hit go and it returns bugs that match that criteria.  I imagine that's implemented by generating a SQL query from the fields selected in the UI.

**In my case, the object which contains the values isn't in a database** so this isn't the obvious answer.  My object is also fairly complex and would require adding multiple tables... and it seemed kind of hackish to create database tables just to then make use of the query engine in the database.  Furthermore, in my application the user basically creates these mappings and they need to get saved to the database.  So, in that case you would end up saving a raw sql query string to the database which sounded like a serious security no no to me.  (But, i'm not a database guy so maybe that's just how things are done).

At this point, I'm really looking for some guidance.  I'm hoping there is some type of design-pattern for what I'm trying to accomplish.  I tried googling various things like "parametric search design pattern" and "rule engines" and didn't find anything that relevant. Is this something LINQ would tackle? I looked at it briefly and it seemed like that would be overkill as well.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1:**
Here is some additional details which I hope will clarify the comments thus far.
I want to let the user create some rules that will be like if object foo.getTemperature() is >= 30 and foo.getTypeOfMsg() == Alert.  Then, retrieve a the "Alert" settings object.  If foo.getTypeOfMsg() == "Test" then get the "Test" object.  The rules are user-driven and so there are infinite possibilities.  Object foo is retrieved by a webservice and I have no need to store it in the database.

Comment: So you're sort of inverting the problem. Instead of running a query against multiple objects, you are running multiple queries against one object? Or is there more than one at a time?

Comment: @Wayne Young - yes it's inverted... but the problem is more how to I perform something that is "query like" (see edit1) to a java object.

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't using a DB to store your object, everything else is the same except the "generate a SQL query" part. What you should look at is the [Specification Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern). Your specification objects basically have a single method called IsSatisfiedBy that takes in the object to see if it meets the specification. Adding some kind of parameter to the specification based on user input seems like a pretty trivial exercise and sounds like it would work in your case.

Not sure I understand the part about "mappings" but since you're not generating a raw SQL query, just make sure your specification objects are serializable and persist it however you want.

LINQ can do this as can plain ol' C# or Java.

Comment: might be useful to mix a scripting engine into this (like Rhino perhaps) to allow the user to build the specification. This is really no more than a glorified, configurable filter, eh? Unless there are optimizations that can be made using indexes, filtering the pool of objects is what's going to be required.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make a data-driven solution, one that can be arbitrarily modified by the user or someone else, or are you looking for something driven internally.

The user driven solution has infinite possibilities that are not known at build time, but it needs some sort of UI.  You must tie the solution to the UI (for instance, show a table and allow them to click to sort on a given row/rows and perhaps let them enter "Filter Criteria" per row) so I'm not sure what advantage your search would provide..

The internally driven solution has a fixed number of possibilities that are all known at build time.  You can code each one up pretty easily--Maybe not as easily as doing it the way you are describing, but not too much more difficult since there are a limited number of solutions you have to implement.